# List all name pairs that appear in a line together and count their frequency

Tags: unix, awk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the following file (2016.csv the head of the file is presented below)

```
Zhichen Gong,Huanhuan Chen
Zhichuan Huang,Tiantian Xie,Ting Zhu,Jianwu Wang,Qingquan Zhang
Zhichuan Huang,Ting Zhu
Zhifei Zhang,Yang Song,Wei Wang 0063,Hairong Qi
```

I am using the following awk loop to find all possible pairs of names that appear together in a line of the above file together.

`awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){for(j=i+1;j<=NF;j++){if($i > $j){k[$i][$j]}else{k[$j][$i]}}}}END{for(n in k){for (l in k[n]){print n,",",l}}}' 2016.csv`

The output of this awk loop is the following :

```
Zhichen Gong , Huanhuan Chen 
Zhichuan Huang , Tiantian Xie
Zhichuan Huang , Ting Zhu
Zhichuan Huang , Jianwu Wang
Zhichuan Huang , Qingquan Zhang
Zhifei Zhang,Yang Song
Zhifei Zhang,Wei Wang 0063
Zhifei Zhang,Hairong Qi
etc
```

This loop works fine and finds all the pairs that appear in a line of the initial file together. The only thing I want to add is a counter next to each line of the awk output, which will show how many times this pair exists in the initial file.

For example, for the above awk output, I want it to be like:

```
Zhichen Gong , Huanhuan Chen, 1
Zhichuan Huang , Tiantian Xie, 1
Zhichuan Huang , Ting Zhu, 2
Zhichuan Huang , Jianwu Wang, 1
Zhichuan Huang , Qingquan Zhang, 1
Zhifei Zhang,Yang Song, 1
Zhifei Zhang,Wei Wang 0063,1 
Zhifei Zhang,Hairong Qi,1
```

Where 1 in the first line (`Zhichen Gong , Huanhuan Chen, 1`) shows that this pair of names exists 1 time in the initial file.

I assume that I just have to add a counter in the awk loop, but I couldn't do it up to now properly.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the input file is a short example just to show you the structure of my file. The output of the awk is sorted differently, so that's why this name does not appear there. However, I checked that the final line pairs of the awk output are correct. I just want to add a counter in the awk loop which will count how many times each pair appeared in the initial file.

Comment: `awk ... | sort | uniq -c`? You'll get the count first, but putting it last shouldn't be hard if you really need it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo this does not work as each pair is unique in this way with the pipe. I want the counter inside the awk loop to search the occurrences on the initial file from which the pairs of each line are extracted

Comment: @Nick15 Can you update the example file to match the example output (or the other way around)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo edited but that's the best I can do. I can't match the exact output with the input as there are 2.7M lines, where each one has a list of names. My awk finds the unique pairs of names that appear together in a line of the file, and I want to simultaneously count the occurrences of each pair.

Comment: Both `Zhichen Gong` and `Huanhuan Chen` appears exactly 1 time each in the input file. It'll be pretty hard to use that example to produce `Zhichen Gong , Huanhuan Chen, 3`.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for exact that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Nick15 you've provided an input sample of 11 lines so all outputs that you show should be based on those same 11 lines; for the sake of this Q&A forget the real file of 2.7M lines and instead provide us with a sample input file (10-15 lines) that also demonstrate some counts > 1 ... then provide the expected output corresponding to this same sample input file; we should be able to take the sample input file and generate the desired output (we can't match your expected output if said output is based on a data set that we have no access to)

Comment: @markp-fuso I'm out of daily votes (Cyrus got my last) so you get it this way instead. :)

Comment: @markp-fuso I edited the post to match my case in this short example. I hope this helps. Anyway, thanks for your advice, I am new here!

Comment: sorry but the expected output is still useless to us ... there are no pairings in the 11-line sample intput that generate a count of 3; also, that 11-line sample input generates 61 distinct name pairings yet your expected output shows only 3 lines; assuming none of the answers provide the desired output ... you'll want to come back and update the question (again) to show the *complete* set of expected output for the 11-line sample input you've provided otherwise we're left guessing as to what the expected output (for the 11-line sample) should look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using OP's 11-line sample as our input:

```
$ cat 2016.csv
Zhichen Gong,Huanhuan Chen
Zhichuan Huang,Tiantian Xie,Ting Zhu,Jianwu Wang,Qingquan Zhang
Zhichuan Huang,Ting Zhu
Zhifei Zhang,Yang Song,Wei Wang 0063,Hairong Qi
Zhihao Huang,Hui Li,Xin Li,Wei He
Zhijun Yin,You Chen,Daniel Fabbri,Jimeng Sun,Bradley A. Malin
Zhipeng Huang 0001,Bogdan Cautis,Reynold Cheng,Yudian Zheng
Zhipeng Huang 0001,Yudian Zheng,Reynold Cheng,Yizhou Sun,Nikos Mamoulis,Xiang Li 0067
Zhiqiang Tao,Hongfu Liu,Sheng Li 0001,Yun Fu 0001
Zhiqiang Xu,Yiping Ke
Zhiyuan Chen 0001,Estevam R. Hruschka Jr.,Bing Liu 0001
```

Making a few tweaks to OP's current code to keep track of counts and then ordering the output 1st by count and then names:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=" , " }
      { for (i=1;i<NF;i++)
            for(j=i+1;j<=NF;j++)
                if   ($i > $j) k[$i][$j]++            # increment counter
                else           k[$j][$i]++            # increment counter
      }
END   { # to sort by count we will create a new 3-dimensional array with the count as the 1st dimension
        for (i in k)
            for (j in k[i]) {
                arr[k[i][j]][i][j]                    # arr[count][i][j]
                delete k[i][j]                        # delete old array entry to limit memory usage
            }
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"         # sort 1st index by count/descending
        for (cnt in arr) {
            PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"      # sort 2nd/3rd indices by name/ascending
            for (i in arr[cnt])
                for (j in arr[cnt][i])
                    print i,j,cnt
        }
      }
' 2016.csv
```

**NOTES:**

- assumes we have enough memory for the 3-dimensional array; then again ...
- memory usage for these 2-/3-dimensional arrays should be significantly smaller than the other answers that utilize a compound index for a 1-dimensional array, ie, ...
- `[bob][smith]` and `[bob][jones]` will require `bob` to be stored once in memory while `[bob,smith]` and `[bob,jones]` will require `bob` to be stored twice in memory
- OP's expected output has a mix of output delimiters; the use of `OFS=" , "` matches the earlier edits by OP; OP can modify `OFS` as needed

This generates the following 61-line output:

```
Yudian Zheng , Reynold Cheng , 2
Zhichuan Huang , Ting Zhu , 2
Zhipeng Huang 0001 , Reynold Cheng , 2
Zhipeng Huang 0001 , Yudian Zheng , 2
Daniel Fabbri , Bradley A. Malin , 1
Estevam R. Hruschka Jr. , Bing Liu 0001 , 1
Jimeng Sun , Bradley A. Malin , 1
Jimeng Sun , Daniel Fabbri , 1
Qingquan Zhang , Jianwu Wang , 1
Reynold Cheng , Bogdan Cautis , 1
Reynold Cheng , Nikos Mamoulis , 1
Sheng Li 0001 , Hongfu Liu , 1
Tiantian Xie , Jianwu Wang , 1
Tiantian Xie , Qingquan Zhang , 1
Ting Zhu , Jianwu Wang , 1
Ting Zhu , Qingquan Zhang , 1
Ting Zhu , Tiantian Xie , 1
Wei He , Hui Li , 1
Wei Wang 0063 , Hairong Qi , 1
Xiang Li 0067 , Nikos Mamoulis , 1
Xiang Li 0067 , Reynold Cheng , 1
Xin Li , Hui Li , 1
Xin Li , Wei He , 1
Yang Song , Hairong Qi , 1
Yang Song , Wei Wang 0063 , 1
Yizhou Sun , Nikos Mamoulis , 1
Yizhou Sun , Reynold Cheng , 1
Yizhou Sun , Xiang Li 0067 , 1
You Chen , Bradley A. Malin , 1
You Chen , Daniel Fabbri , 1
You Chen , Jimeng Sun , 1
Yudian Zheng , Bogdan Cautis , 1
Yudian Zheng , Nikos Mamoulis , 1
Yudian Zheng , Xiang Li 0067 , 1
Yudian Zheng , Yizhou Sun , 1
Yun Fu 0001 , Hongfu Liu , 1
Yun Fu 0001 , Sheng Li 0001 , 1
Zhichen Gong , Huanhuan Chen , 1
Zhichuan Huang , Jianwu Wang , 1
Zhichuan Huang , Qingquan Zhang , 1
Zhichuan Huang , Tiantian Xie , 1
Zhifei Zhang , Hairong Qi , 1
Zhifei Zhang , Wei Wang 0063 , 1
Zhifei Zhang , Yang Song , 1
Zhihao Huang , Hui Li , 1
Zhihao Huang , Wei He , 1
Zhihao Huang , Xin Li , 1
Zhijun Yin , Bradley A. Malin , 1
Zhijun Yin , Daniel Fabbri , 1
Zhijun Yin , Jimeng Sun , 1
Zhijun Yin , You Chen , 1
Zhipeng Huang 0001 , Bogdan Cautis , 1
Zhipeng Huang 0001 , Nikos Mamoulis , 1
Zhipeng Huang 0001 , Xiang Li 0067 , 1
Zhipeng Huang 0001 , Yizhou Sun , 1
Zhiqiang Tao , Hongfu Liu , 1
Zhiqiang Tao , Sheng Li 0001 , 1
Zhiqiang Tao , Yun Fu 0001 , 1
Zhiqiang Xu , Yiping Ke , 1
Zhiyuan Chen 0001 , Bing Liu 0001 , 1
Zhiyuan Chen 0001 , Estevam R. Hruschka Jr. , 1
```

---

If the order of the output does not matter the `END{...}` block can be simplified to the following:

```
END   { for (i in k)
            for (j in k[i])
                print i,j,k[i][j]
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

> find all possible pairs of names that appear together their counts

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk -F, -v OFS=" , " '
{
   for (i=1; i<NF; i++)
      ++fq[$i OFS $(i+1)]
}
END {
   for (i in fq) print i, fq[i]
}' file
```

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto What does `::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::` mean? Perhaps it'd be better if you wrote an answer instead? The comment looks messy.

Comment: @TedLyngmo : absolutely nothing  - just to pad it to have codes in same line instead having them wrap-around (and I don't trust merely padding spaces that won't get automatically squeezed by the backend processor). Although padding using single quotes, or, preferably, byte \140, alternating between one space and one quote, would be least visually intrusive, those may have special meaning in its formatting lingo

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto You know you can use single backticks to `format` stuff even in comments?

Comment: @TedLyngmo : ahh didn't know that. cuz in comments section, leading edge un-escaped underscores behave strangely, so i (incorrectly) thought it has its own syntax. Thanks for the tip =)

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto You're welcome! If you can make your improvement suggestions work in the comments, please try it out. If it becomes too messy, please put up a proper answer so we see it clearly. :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo : lemme try -  just directly set `SUBSEP = OFS` in a `BEGIN` section, then array incrementing becomes just `++fq[ $( i ) , $( i + 1 ) ]` ;  you can even combine the setting of all 3 together `SUBSEP = OFS = " " ( FS = "," ) " "`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Much better. Still wished you'd put it up as an answer :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo : i can't do that in good conscience - that's anubhava's work not mine, and i was merely offering my 2 cents instead of my own solution.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Then propose an edit to this answer. I'm not sure at what rep. you would automatically edit it or when it requires approval. If you still need approval, that would be perfect.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: You probably meant this: `awk -F, 'BEGIN{SUBSEP = OFS = " " FS " "} {for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) ++fq[$i, $(i+1)]} END {for (i in fq) print i, fq[i]}' file`

Comment: That would only output some adjacent pairs and would skip every other field, e.g. given `a,b,c` it wouldn't find `a,c`, or `b,c`, just `a,b`.

Comment: @anubhava  : i meant `BEGIN { SUBSEP = OFS = " " ( FS = "," ) " " } ` - placing the `-F,` outside defeats the whole purpose. same for rest. The `for` loop could also be less verbose by counting down `from NF` instead of `towards NF`, but that's just a matter of styling mostly. That said, I haven't actually checked the code for correctness, merely suggesting syntactical slim downs and streamlining without altering the original meaning of ur code

Comment: @EdMorton: Indeed for `a,b,c` it will print pairs `a,b` and `b,c` because OP asked for: `find all possible pairs of names that appear together`

Comment: It wouldn't have found `b,c` when I left my comment because the `i+=2` you had in the loop at that time (I see you've changed it to `i++` now) skipped over `b` but you also trimmed too much of the OPs text in your comment, they actually said `find all possible pairs of names that appear together in a line` - note the **in a line** part at the end, they're not just interested in contiguous pairs but all combinations of strings on each line.

Comment: I believe you read it correctly Ed and `together` confused me to some extent with lack of good sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Using a sensible sample input file so we can tell at a glance if the script worked or not because the expected output is obvious:

```
$ cat file
a,b,c
c,a
e,d
```

This will do what you want using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        for (j=i+1; j<=NF; j++) {
            cnt[( $i < $j ? $i FS $j : $j FS $i )]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    for ( pair in cnt ) {
        print pair, cnt[pair]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
a,b,1
a,c,2
d,e,1
b,c,1
```

or if you want it sorted:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort
a,b,1
a,c,2
b,c,1
d,e,1
```

With the OPs provided sample input:

```
$ cat file2
Zhichen Gong,Huanhuan Chen
Zhichuan Huang,Tiantian Xie,Ting Zhu,Jianwu Wang,Qingquan Zhang
Zhichuan Huang,Ting Zhu
Zhifei Zhang,Yang Song,Wei Wang 0063,Hairong Qi
```

we have:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 | sort
Hairong Qi,Wei Wang 0063,1
Hairong Qi,Yang Song,1
Hairong Qi,Zhifei Zhang,1
Huanhuan Chen,Zhichen Gong,1
Jianwu Wang,Qingquan Zhang,1
Jianwu Wang,Tiantian Xie,1
Jianwu Wang,Ting Zhu,1
Jianwu Wang,Zhichuan Huang,1
Qingquan Zhang,Tiantian Xie,1
Qingquan Zhang,Ting Zhu,1
Qingquan Zhang,Zhichuan Huang,1
Tiantian Xie,Ting Zhu,1
Tiantian Xie,Zhichuan Huang,1
Ting Zhu,Zhichuan Huang,2
Wei Wang 0063,Yang Song,1
Wei Wang 0063,Zhifei Zhang,1
Yang Song,Zhifei Zhang,1
```